# Should I have to use ember - cli to use version ember 1.10.0?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm running my app using Ember App Kit, version 1.9.1. If I want to move to ember version 1.10.0 I have to upgrade to ember-cli?

Comment: Is there an Ember App Kit 1.9.1?  you should really be using ember-cli. Ember App Kit from what I know is deprecated and ember-cli is the official endorsed way to develop ember apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Ember App Kit is deprecated since long time. You shouldn't be using that even for 1.9.1, so answer is yes - you should upgrade to Ember CLI as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks. Actually am using EAK for 1.9.1 but with some deprecations.